# Consulta con join me trae mas registros de los esperados

Tags: sql, postgresql

Necesito hacer un join entre 2 tablas, tengo la tabla persona la cual contiene 58422 registros, y tengo la tabla evaluación la cual contiene 59175 registros
lo que necesito es que solo me traiga al hacer el join el total de la tabla persona y no el de la tabla evaluación

```
select
    p.codigo_persona,
    ev.codigo_evaluacion
    from vulnerabilidad.t_persona p
    join vulnerabilidad.t_evaluacion as ev 
         ON p.codigo_persona = ev.codigo_persona`
```

una persona puede tener varias evaluaciones pero solo necesito los registros de las personas no la cantidad de evaluaciones, claro con los datos de la tabla evaluacion.

Comment: Una persona puede tener múltiples evaluaciones, por lo que la pregunta  sería, si solo quieres mostrar una fila por persona, ¿cual de todas las evaluaciones deseas mostrar?

Comment: la ultima guardada

Comment: Deberías entonces postear la definición de la tabla. Cómo sabemos cuál es "la última guardada"?

Comment: ok, pero si por ahora necesito solo tener 1 evaluacion indiferentemente si es la primera o la ultima? hay una forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Es que para darte una respuesta mas exacta, necesitaríamos saber el nombre y tipo del campo en el que hay que basarse para saber si es la primera o la ultima evaluacion.En este tipo de preguntas tambien ayuda mucho crear un fiddle de ejemplo para que los que quieran ayudarte puedan probar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si necesitas cualquier evaluación indiferente si es la primera o última, una opción sería usar `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY codigo_persona ORDER BY codigo_persona) AS RN
    FROM vulnerabilidad.t_evaluacion
)
SELECT  p.codigo_persona,
        ev.codigo_evaluacion
FROM vulnerabilidad.t_persona p
INNER JOIN CTE as ev 
    ON p.codigo_persona = ev.codigo_persona
WHERE ev.RN = 1
;
```

Comment: @Pikoh En efecto ;), no lo ví

Comment: Parece que el equivalente a `CROSS APPLY` en postgresql es [LATERAL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11473447/579895)

Comment: @Pikoh sí, hay un lateral join, pero no es exacto a `CROSS APPLY`, así que mejor descarté esa alternativa

Comment: Ok, usted es el experto ;)